# Programming API for Lightning Network

Tags: lightning-network

I am trying to learn how to work with Bitcoin and the Lightning Network from a programming perspective.

I saw that bitcoin-core was using: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#bitcoin-core-apis in order to allow one to work with RPCs (or APIs).

Is there something similar for the Lightning Network? When using an API for the Lightning Network, would Authentication/Authorization be necessary?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `lnd`, it's at https://api.lightning.community

Note that there are additional resources at https://dev.lightning.community